# localhost works fine, hosted errors with "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'record' of null"

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, codeigniter

I've encountered an error:

`**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'record' of null.**`

I want to display data via ajax in a table, but there is a problem. When I open the page from localhost it works fine, but when I open it from a hosted site there *is* a problem.

```
 if(data.record != null ) {
    $.each(data.record, function(index, element){
      var post_status = '';
      if(element.post_status == 'pending'){
        post_status = '(pending)';
      }

      $('table#tbl-artikel').find('tbody').append(
        '<tr>'+
        '  <td width="2%"><input type="checkbox" name="post_id[]" value="'+element.post_ID+'"></td>'+
        '  <td width="50%"><a class="link-edit" href="artikel#edit?id='+element.post_ID+'">'+element.post_title+'</a> <strong>'+post_status+'</strong></td>'+
        '  <td width="10%"><i class="icon-comment-alt"></i> <span class="value">'+element.comment_count+'</span></td>'+
        '  <td width="10%"><i class="icon-eye-open"></i> <span class="value">'+element.post_counter+'</span></td>'+
        '  <td width="12%"><i class="icon-time"></i> <span class="value">'+moment(element.post_date).fromNow()+'</span></td>'+
        '  <td width="16%" class="td-actions">'+
        '    <a href="artikel#edit?id='+element.post_ID+'" class="link-edit btn btn-small btn-info"><i class="btn-icon-only icon-pencil"></i> Edit</a>'+
        '    <a href="artikel#hapus?id='+element.post_ID+'" class="btn btn-invert btn-small btn-info"><i class="btn-icon-only icon-remove" id="hapus_1"></i> Hapus</a>'+
        '  </td>'+
        '</tr>'                
      )
    });
  }else{
    console.log(data);
  }
```

Comment: just console data , data is null

Comment: The error is ___very___ clear: _"Cannot read property 'record' of null"_. This means that in `data.record`, `data` is `null`.

Comment: Please provide example of data which cause an error

Answer (score 1):

change your code to:

```js
 if(data != null && data.record != null ) {
    $.each(data.record, function(index, element){
      var post_status = '';
      if(element.post_status == 'pending'){
        post_status = '(pending)';
      }

      $('table#tbl-artikel').find('tbody').append(
        '<tr>'+
        '  <td width="2%"><input type="checkbox" name="post_id[]" value="'+element.post_ID+'"></td>'+
        '  <td width="50%"><a class="link-edit" href="artikel#edit?id='+element.post_ID+'">'+element.post_title+'</a> <strong>'+post_status+'</strong></td>'+
        '  <td width="10%"><i class="icon-comment-alt"></i> <span class="value">'+element.comment_count+'</span></td>'+
        '  <td width="10%"><i class="icon-eye-open"></i> <span class="value">'+element.post_counter+'</span></td>'+
        '  <td width="12%"><i class="icon-time"></i> <span class="value">'+moment(element.post_date).fromNow()+'</span></td>'+
        '  <td width="16%" class="td-actions">'+
        '    <a href="artikel#edit?id='+element.post_ID+'" class="link-edit btn btn-small btn-info"><i class="btn-icon-only icon-pencil"></i> Edit</a>'+
        '    <a href="artikel#hapus?id='+element.post_ID+'" class="btn btn-invert btn-small btn-info"><i class="btn-icon-only icon-remove" id="hapus_1"></i> Hapus</a>'+
        '  </td>'+
        '</tr>'                
      )
    });
  }else{
    console.log(data);
  }
```